Lombok @ToString.Exclude decorator is not working
I am not able to exclude password field from the response when sending a POST request to /users. Below you can find the User entity and the User controller. It also doesn't work if I exclude the @NotNull and @Size decorators. I saw there a solution to downgrade the Lombok version. But is it possible now with the newer version? Any suggestions?
User entity:
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document("users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String userId;

    @NotNull(message = "Email is required")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 100, message = "Email must be between 5 and 100 characters")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "First name is required")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "First name must be between 5 and 50 characters")
    private String firstname;

    @NotNull(message = "Last name is required")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50, message = "Last name must be between 5 and 50 characters")
    private String lastname;


    @NotNull(message = "Password is required")
    @Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "Password must be between 5 and 20 characters")
    private String password;

    // !! Password is also sent as part of the response.
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}

UserController:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Validated
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(userService.createUser(user));
    }
}


Lombok ToString.Exclude doesn't exclude it from response, ONLY from toString. To exclude it from Response you would need a Jackson annotation @JsonIgnore on a getter (you would have to use a explicit getter, not lombok one, and put annotation on it)

I added the @JsonIgnore annotation on the getter method public String getPassword(){return password}, However, when sending a post request. I get "Password is required" as a response, although I sent the correct request. I also tried adding the annotation above private String password, same issue.

you shouldn't have gotten that error from setting JsonIgnore on a getter, you definetely will get the error if you set it on a setter and/or the field itself. You should readup on Jackson and JsonIgnore to understand how they work

Thanks for the link, I did follow the documentation. However, as I mentioned in the post, I believe due to the other annotations @NotNull and @Size, @JsonIgnore is not working as intended.

yes, but that is expected. @NonNull requires password to be part of the @RequestBody. And @JsonIgnore placed on getter will only affect Response (NOT RequestBody). If you were to place @JsonIgnore on field or setter then it would affect Deserialization and result in Validation error from @NonNull
